# Increase a counter for each changed row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Standard, which doesn't have a `SEQUENCE` feature.

An external system reads data from several dedicated tables of the main database.
External system keeps a copy of data and periodically checks for changes in the data and refreshes its copy.

To make the sync efficient I want to transfer only rows that were updated or inserted since the previous sync. (The rows are never deleted).
To know which rows were updated or inserted since the last sync there is a `bigint` column `RowUpdateCounter` in each table.

The idea is that whenever a row is inserted or updated, the number in its `RowUpdateCounter` column would change.
The values that go into the `RowUpdateCounter` column should be taken from an ever increasing sequence of numbers.
Values in the `RowUpdateCounter` column should be unique and each new value stored in a table should be greater than any previous value.

Please see the scripts that show the desired behaviour.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RowUpdateCounter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RowUpdateCounter] ON [dbo].[Test]
(
    [RowUpdateCounter] ASC
)
GO
```

**INSERT some rows**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]
    ([ID]
    ,[Value]
    ,[RowUpdateCounter])
VALUES
(1, 'A', ???),
(2, 'B', ???),
(3, 'C', ???),
(4, 'D', ???);
```

**Expected result**

```
+----+-------+------------------+
| ID | Value | RowUpdateCounter |
+----+-------+------------------+
|  1 | A     |                1 |
|  2 | B     |                2 |
|  3 | C     |                3 |
|  4 | D     |                4 |
+----+-------+------------------+
```

The generated values in `RowUpdateCounter` can be different, say, `5, 3, 7, 9`. They should be unique and they should be greater than 0, since we started from empty table.

**INSERT and UPDATE some rows**

```
DECLARE @NewValues TABLE (ID int NOT NULL, Value varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @NewValues (ID, Value) VALUES
(3, 'E'),
(4, 'F'),
(5, 'G'),
(6, 'H');

MERGE INTO dbo.Test WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Dst
USING
(
    SELECT ID, Value
    FROM @NewValues
)
AS Src ON Dst.ID = Src.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
     Dst.Value            = Src.Value
    ,Dst.RowUpdateCounter = ???
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    (ID
    ,Value
    ,RowUpdateCounter)
VALUES
    (Src.ID
    ,Src.Value
    ,???)
;
```

**Expected result**

```
+----+-------+------------------+
| ID | Value | RowUpdateCounter |
+----+-------+------------------+
|  1 | A     |                1 |
|  2 | B     |                2 |
|  3 | E     |                5 |
|  4 | F     |                6 |
|  5 | G     |                7 |
|  6 | H     |                8 |
+----+-------+------------------+
```

- `RowUpdateCounter` for rows with ID `1,2` should remain as is, because these rows were not changed.
- `RowUpdateCounter` for rows with ID `3,4` should change, because they were updated.
- `RowUpdateCounter` for rows with ID `5,6` should change, because they were inserted.
- `RowUpdateCounter` for all changed rows should be greater than 4 (the last `RowUpdateCounter` from the sequence).

The order in which new values (`5,6,7,8`) are assigned to changed rows doesn't really matter.
The new values can have gaps, e.g. `15,26,47,58`, but they should never decrease.

There are several tables with such counters in the database. 
It doesn't matter if all of them use the single global sequence for their numbers, or each table has its own individual sequence.

---

I don't want to use a column with a datetime stamp instead of an integer counter, because:

- The clock on the server can jump both forward and backward. Especially when it is on a virtual machine.
- The values returned by system functions like `SYSDATETIME` are the same for all affected rows.
  The sync process should be able to read changes in batches.
  For example, if batch size is 3 rows, then after the `MERGE` step above the sync process would read only rows `E,F,G`.
  When the sync process is run next time it would continue from row `H`.

---

The way I'm doing it now is rather ugly.

Since there is no `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server 2008, I emulate the `SEQUENCE` by a dedicated table with `IDENTITY` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392196/4116017). This in itself is pretty ugly and exacerbated by the fact that I need to generate not a single, but a batch of numbers at once.

Then, I have an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT` trigger on each table with the `RowUpdateCounter` and generate required sets of numbers there.

In the `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `MERGE` queries I set `RowUpdateCounter` to 0, which is replaced by the correct values in the trigger. The `???` in the queries 
above are `0`.

It works, but is there an easier solution?

Comment: Could you use row version / timestamp? It's a binary field but the value will change every time the row is updated

Comment: @JamesZ, I need to know the order in which the rows were changed. The sync process reads the MAX Counter from the outdated copy of the table and then it know to fetch only rows that have Counter more than that value. The `rowversion` wouldn't give me this possibility, if I correctly understand what it is... Is it guaranteed to be ever increasing?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - yes. [Each database has a counter **that is incremented** for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a rowversion column within the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith, I completely forgot about `rowversion`. It looks very tempting. My only concern is that all examples of its use that I've seen so far revolve around detecting whether a single row changed. I need an efficient way of knowing what **set** of rows changed since a certain moment. Besides, is it possible to miss an update?

Comment: @MartinSmith time=0: last rowversion value is, say, 122. time=1: Transaction `A` updates a row, its rowversion changes to 123, `A` is not committed yet. time=2: Transaction `B` updates another row, its rowversion changes to 124. time=3: `B` commits. time=4: sync process runs and fetches all rows with rowversion > 122, which means rows updated only by `B`. time=5: `A` commits. Result: changes by `A` will never be picked up by the sync process. Am I wrong? Maybe some clever use of `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION` will help?

Comment: The query for `rowversion > 122` will be blocked until A commits unless you are using `NOLOCK` or `READPAST` (or snapshot)

Comment: @MartinSmith, I ran a quick check. Indeed, SELECT query was waiting for pending transaction to complete. My next concern was related to possible reset of this internal counter after backup/restore. Your [answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51026/why-does-dbts-increase-after-backup-restore) is very detailed and explains what is going on. Overall, it looks like `rowversion` is exactly what I need. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `ROWVERSION` column for this.

[The documentation states that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or
>   update operation that is performed on a table that contains a
>   rowversion column within the database.

The values are `BINARY(8)` and you should consider them as `BINARY` rather than `BIGINT` as after `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` it goes on to `0x80...` and starts working up from `-9223372036854775808`if treated as a signed `bigint`.

A full worked example is below. Maintaining the index on the `ROWVERSION` column will be expensive if you have lots of updates so you might want to test your workload both with and without to see if it is worth the cost.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
  (
     [ID]               [INT] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY,
     [Value]            [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
     [RowUpdateCounter] [ROWVERSION] NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
  )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]
            ([ID],
             [Value])
VALUES     (1,'Foo'),
            (2,'Bar'),
            (3,'Baz');

DECLARE @RowVersion_LastSynch ROWVERSION = MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION();

UPDATE [dbo].[Test]
SET    [Value] = 'X'
WHERE  [ID] = 2;

DECLARE @RowVersion_ThisSynch ROWVERSION = MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION();

SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[Test]
WHERE  [RowUpdateCounter] >= @RowVersion_LastSynch
       AND RowUpdateCounter < @RowVersion_ThisSynch;

/*TODO: Store @RowVersion_ThisSynch somewhere*/

DROP TABLE [dbo].[Test]
```

Comment: Thank you. After reading the docs I think that instead of `@@DBTS` there should be [`MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx), and if using `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` comparison `<=` should become `<` and `>` become `>=`.

Comment: According to the docs there is a material difference between `@@DBTS` and `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` if there are active uncommitted transactions. *If an application uses `@@DBTS` rather than `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION`, it is possible to miss changes that are active when synchronization occurs.*

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - yep, agreed, edited.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the `IDENTITY` option?

For example:

```
[RowUpdateCounter] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,2)
```

where

- 1 --> Starting value
- 2 --> each new row is incremented by this

This is similar to SEQUENCE in Oracle.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any "AUTOINCREMENT option"

Comment: yes. It is supported by Access. SQL server supports IDENTITY option. I have updated my reply above. Thanks !!

Comment: `IDENTITY` doesn't do what is required regarding automatically incrementing on *both updates and inserts*.

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanPadhi, I need to know what rows have been updated. I don't see how simple `IDENTITY` can help.